# Failing preg_match pattern over entirely valid value

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I used regexpal.com to test my regexp against the data Wordpress is trying to compare to and it fails, look at this and tell me if you see the problem?

The regexp

```
"#^json/(.+?)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$#"
```

The content to match

```
json/trips
```

These works, the previous one doesn't

```
json/trips/0
json/trips/13
json/fullticket/9805048001130122361809
```

If I try all these in regexpal they all work, but in wordpress, only the one that doesn't contain the id of the element I want to fetch fails the others work fine.

Interrestingly enough, the $matches return this:

```
array
0 => string 'json/trips' (length=10)
1 => string 't' (length=1)
2 => string 'rips' (length=4)
```

Comment: Note that some of my ids contain letters, i musn't remove the "a-zA-Z" part and i should actually add "\-" in there cause some of my ids contain "-"s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer after tweaking the wordpress rewrite rule a bit more ends up being:

```
data/([^/]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*))?$
```

Note: i changed json to data in the new scenario so i don't mess up the custom post type rules

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp instead :

```
#^json/([^/]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$#
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => json/trips
    [1] => trips
    [2] => 
)
```

Comment: Sorry i found my answer a few seconds ago, at least i'll upvote you :)